# What is the best tool to write acceptance tests for native iOS apps?

Tags: testing, automation, acceptance-testing, calabash, frank

I have searched and found 2 tools which I think most popular right now are Calabash and Frank .But I don't know which is better one. Any suggestion would be appreciated!

Comment: Tool recommendation questions are off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

It completely depend on your testing requirement which tool to use :

[Here are few most popular Open Source Mobile Test Automation Frameworks](http://dary.de/2012/03/open-source-mobile-test-automation-frameworks/)